# background transparency in css

Tags: html, css, background

I need background transparent only for black div. but it is applying even for buttons also which are in a tag.

Here is my link
http://jsfiddle.net/rCGJH/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use RGBa (with an RGB fallback) colours with the opacity set there. This will just do the background - http://jsfiddle.net/spacebeers/rCGJH/13/

```
/* Fallback for web browsers that doesn't support RGBa */
background: rgb(0, 0, 0);
/* RGBa with 0.5 opacity */
background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
```

Otherwise just use an image with the opacity set on there. That would cover all browsers.

Comment: No, personally I'd just use an image but it's handy to know about RGBa

Comment: But y is it not applying to the top arrow?

Comment: You need to change the opacity in the border color to match the background (0.5).

Comment: Updated the Fiddle in the answer to include that.

Answer (score 0):

```
background-color:rgba(255,0,0,0.5);
```